# (Proof Check) For a commutative ring $R$ the nilradical is contained in the Jacobson radical.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider an arbitrary simple $R$-module $M$ and an arbitrary nilpotent element $a \in R$ such that $a^n = 0.$ We want to show that $aM = 0.$ So consider the map $\phi: M \rightarrow M$ such that $m \mapsto a^{n - 1}m.$ Clearly, since $R$ is commutative, $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Now, suppose $\ker(\phi)$ is nontrivial. Then $M/\ker(\phi)$ is a proper submodule of $M$ contradicting the fact that $M$ is simple. Hence, $\ker(\phi)$ is trivial. Thus, every element of $M$ can be written in the form $a^{n - 1}m$ for some $m \in M.$ It follows that $aM = 0.$

Is my proof ok? I appreciate any feedback!

Comment: A quotient is not a submodule!

Comment: For future reference, if you don't know of any particular problem in your proof, it is better to post something like this as a question, noting that you need feedback on your solution, and then self-answer in the solutions. The goal is to avoid the situation when answers basically have to be "yeah that's fine." Here, that is masked a bit because your answer *did* have lots of problems. However, in the future it may well be the opposite case! And if you *know* a portion of your proof has a problem, you can ask specifically about that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the proof is good, but not well developed.

If the map $\phi(m)=a^{n-1}m$ has non trivial kernel (that is, $\ker\phi\ne M$), then its kernel is $0$ and $\phi$ is injective; therefore its image is not $\{0\}$, hence $\phi$ is surjective. Therefore every element of $M$ is of the form $a^{n-1}m$.

---

The endomorphism ring of a simple module is a division ring (any nonzero endomorphism is an isomorphism); since $\phi$ is a nilpotent element of this ring, it is zero.

Alternatively, with a different characterization of the Jacobson radical: when $x$ is nilpotent, then $1+x$ is invertible; therefore $1+ax$ is invertible for every $x$.

Comment: The proof is ok? He took a quotient of $M$ and called it a submodule...

Comment: @MooS Standard abuse of language: $M/\ker\phi$ is (isomorphic to) a submodule of $M$.

Comment: I do not think that someone, who has such a tiny proof checked here, would refer to that as "standard".

Comment: Furthermore in general, even if $\operatorname{ker} \phi$ is non-zero, it is not true that the $M/\operatorname{ker} \phi \cong \operatorname{image} \phi$ is a proper submodule. It holds in this case, but one has to say something about that.

Furthermore, it could be that $\operatorname{ker} \phi =M$ and in thi case you get $a^{n-1}M=0$. Then one has to say how this leads to $aM=0$.

The proof has so many flaws, I do not even know where to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is helping me a lot !!!!

Comment: Also you said 'he' but I am a girl, thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for that, nevertheless it is impossible to write he/she each and every time one refers to the person, who posed the question. If it says only 'he', one usually means the 'original poster' without thinking about the gender. I do not see how to handle this otherwise.

Comment: @MooS I only had short time to give a more detailed reply to your comment; now I fixed the first paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is much easier: Since $M$ is simple, we have $aM=0$ or $aM=M$. The latter can be iterated to $M=a^nM=0$, hence $aM=0$ in either case.